# Removing the namespace( xsd ,xs1 and <?xml version="1.0"?> ) in xml serialization c#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have two classes Room and CHILD_RATE classes :
When I am serializing the data , I am getting below mentioned xml(Sample 1:) :
But I want the namespaces( xsd ,xs1 and  ) to be removed.i.e. I want the out put in Sample 2: format

```
[XmlRoot]


 public class Room
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public int Occupancy { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        [XmlArray(ElementName="CHILDREN")]
        public List<CHILD_RATE> Childs { get; set; }
    }


    public class CHILD_RATE
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public int CHILD_AGE { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public int CHILD_QUANTITY { get; set; }
    }

Sample 1:


 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfRoom xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Room>
    <Occupancy>7</Occupancy>
    <Quantity>3</Quantity>
    <CHILDREN>
      <CHILD_RATE CHILD_AGE="1" CHILD_QUANTITY="2" />
      <CHILD_RATE CHILD_AGE="4" CHILD_QUANTITY="1" />
    </CHILDREN>
  </Room>
  <Room>
    <Occupancy>8</Occupancy>
    <Quantity>3</Quantity>
    <CHILDREN>
      <CHILD_RATE CHILD_AGE="3" CHILD_QUANTITY="3" />
      <CHILD_RATE CHILD_AGE="7" CHILD_QUANTITY="2" />
    </CHILDREN>
  </Room>
  <Room>
    <Occupancy>2</Occupancy>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <CHILDREN />
  </Room>
  <Room>
    <Occupancy>5</Occupancy>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <CHILDREN />
  </Room>
</ArrayOfRoom>
```

I want Output  like :

Sample 2:

```
 <Room>
    <Occupancy>7</Occupancy>
    <Quantity>3</Quantity>
    <CHILDREN>
      <CHILD_RATE CHILD_AGE="1" CHILD_QUANTITY="2" />
      <CHILD_RATE CHILD_AGE="4" CHILD_QUANTITY="1" />
    </CHILDREN>
  </Room>
  <Room>
    <Occupancy>8</Occupancy>
    <Quantity>3</Quantity>
    <CHILDREN>
      <CHILD_RATE CHILD_AGE="3" CHILD_QUANTITY="3" />
      <CHILD_RATE CHILD_AGE="7" CHILD_QUANTITY="2" />
    </CHILDREN>
  </Room>
  <Room>
    <Occupancy>2</Occupancy>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <CHILDREN />
  </Room>
  <Room>
    <Occupancy>5</Occupancy>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <CHILDREN />
  </Room>
```

For serialization I am using :

```
public string CreaateXML(List<Room> room)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Room>));
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.Serialize(stream, room);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());

    }
```

i.e , I don't want

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <ArrayOfRoom xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org /2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a empty namespace. Modify base on your code

```
public string CreaateXML(List<Room> room)
{
        var xmlnamespace = new Original.XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        xmlnamespace.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = omitDeclaration;
        settings.Encoding = encoding;
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings);


        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Room>));
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.Serialize(writer, room, xmlnamespace);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());

}
```

Comment: Hi @James : Thanks, Namespaces are removed.
But I am still getting , <?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfRoom> , which I don't need.
Please suggest

Comment: @palakmehta I have update my answer, so you can try it

Answer (score 0):

```
 XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings);

            XmlSerializerNamespaces names = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            names.Add("", "");

            XmlSerializer cs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Room>));

            cs.Serialize(writer, room, names);

            ms.Flush();
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
            var xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
            return xml;
```